# Rails Mechanize how to select a form based on its name

Tags: python, ruby, mechanize

I fail to select a form using its name with Mechanize in rails. The source code of the page I am trying to take data from looks like this:

```
var strAccesBamPoppin = "";
if(!emailing){          
        strAccesBamPoppin = '<form name="bamaccess_' + idTCM + '" id="bamaccess_' + idTCM + '"   class="bamaccessDecloi" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="'+chemin+'"'; 
        if (typeConnexion == "True") {strAccesBamPoppinPoppin = strAccesBamPoppin +'>';
```

With python, I would use something like

```
XX.select_form('bamaccess')
```

What would be the equivalent with Ruby? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
XX.forms.select{|x| x[:name][/bamaccess/]}
```

The above should work for sure.

```
XX.forms_with(name: /bamaccess/)
```

This will return an array of all the forms with a name containing bamaccess

Keep in mind that /string/ is a regexp since the name will contain bamaccess_*****